# Sustituir Div en Intervalo de tiempo sin transiciones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

También me valdría sustituir directamente caracteres en intervalos de tiempo cíclicos si creeis que es más limpio. Aquí está el código con el que estoy trabajando.

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=picture1]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide(10);
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).hide(function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).show(10);
        })
    }, 1500)
})
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=picture2]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        })
    }, 900)
})
```

```css
body {margin:0; color:rgba(0,255,22,1.00); background:black; font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace; font-size:6px; line-height:7px; display:inline-block;}
.position { text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picture1">
    <span class="quote">A</span>
</div>

<div id="picture12">B</div>

<div id="picture2">
    <span class="quote">A</span>
</div>
<div id="picture22">B</div>
```

Comment: Ahora mismo no está muy claro qué es lo que se quiere en esta pregunta. Por favor, añade una explicación mejor de lo que quieres: ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer?¿cúal debería ser el resultado si fuera bien?¿por qué es incorrecto el código de arriba?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro mi problema es que necesito que el cambio sea inmediato, no ese apagarse paulatino, que el ojo no pueda percibir ni un momento en el que no hay ninguna letra.
Espero haberme explicado mejor y muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Creo que ahora comprendo mejor. Lo que quieres es que la letra desaparezca de golpe sin que sea una transición. ¿Es eso correcto?

Comment: Exacto @AlvaroMontoro pero que el resto siga funcionando igual (cíclico e infinito)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la letra desaparezca de golpe sin que sea una transición, debes indicar que la duración de la transición sea 0. Si no lo indicas, el valor por defecto será 400 milisegundos (como se indica en la [documentación de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)).

El cambio sería rápido, donde ahora haces:

```
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
```

deberías añadir una duración de 0 como haces en el fadeIn:

```
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
        i = (i + 1) % len
        $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
```

Y eso debería solucionar el problema. Aquí dejo una demo:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=picture1]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide(10);
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).hide(0, function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).show(10);
        })
    }, 1500)
})
jQuery(function () {
    var $els = $('div[id^=picture2]'),
        i = 0,
        len = $els.length;

    $els.slice(1).hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
            i = (i + 1) % len
            $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        })
    }, 900)
})
```

```css
body {margin:0; color:rgba(0,255,22,1.00); background:black; font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace; font-size:6px; line-height:7px; display:inline-block;}
.position { text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picture1">
    <span class="quote">A</span>
</div>

<div id="picture12">B</div>

<div id="picture2">
    <span class="quote">A</span>
</div>
<div id="picture22">B</div>
```